# No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I updated ASP.NET 5 framework beta-8 packages with RC ones on previously working application. After I got it running next error occured in the startup process:

> InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.d__12.MoveNext()

```
var defaultPolicy =
    new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();

services.AddMvc(setup =>
{
    setup.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy)); // Error occurs here
});
```

If anyone had similar problem, I'd appreciate your idea or solution on what might have gone wrong. Explanation of this exception is also appreciated.

**Startup.cs**

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;
using SuperUserMVC.Configuration;
using SuperUserMVC.Extensions;
using SuperUserMVC.GlobalModules;
using System;

namespace SuperUserMVC
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<AppSettingsBase>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettingsBase"));
            services.Configure<ConnectionString>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString"));

            services.AddSqlServerCache(cache =>
            {
                cache.ConnectionString = Configuration.Get<string>("ASPState:ConnectionString");
                cache.SchemaName = Configuration.Get<string>("ASPState:Schema");
                cache.TableName = Configuration.Get<string>("ASPState:Table");
            });

            services.AddSession(session =>
            {
                session.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
            });

            // Only allow authenticated users.
            var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();

            // Add MVC services to the services container.
            services.AddMvc(setup =>
            {
                setup.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
            });

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());
            builder.Populate(services);

            var container = builder.Build();

            return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            // Catch unhandled exception in pipeline.
            bool isProductionEnvironment = Configuration.Get<bool>("environmentVariables:isProductionEnvironment");
            app.UseCustomUnhandledException(isProductionEnvironment, Configuration.Get<string>("defaultErrorPagePath"));

            // Log requests.
            app.UseVisitLogger(isProductionEnvironment);

            // Session must be used before MVC routes.
            app.UseSession();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/");
                options.CookieName = "MyCookie";
                options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
                options.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheSessionStore();
            });

            AutoMapperInitializer.Init();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Route configuration.
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "AreaDefault",
                    template: "{area:exists=Demo}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just started to develop with asp.net with the last beta (created a new project and then enhanced it a bit) and also had problems after update to RC, because they have changed various BASE-things. Unfortunately I don't have found any description, how to change existing projects to be compatible. So... I then have recreated my project from scratch from a new template, to be fully compatible. As RC is is supported for production by MS, I think (hope so) there don't will be such changes in the future (release version Q1 2016).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try setting `options.AutomaticChallenge = true;` in your cookies options and it should work.

`options.AutomaticAuthentication` was split into `options.AutomaticAuthenticate` and `options.AutomaticChallenge`. If the last one is left to `false`, an exception is thrown because no authentication middleware handles the challenge applied by the authorization filter.

Comment: What if your not using Cookies?

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor, I set it directly to Google authentication options

Comment: There is no options.AutomaticChallenge in asp.net core 2.0

Answer (score 49):

Hopefully this will help somebody else because I just spent a lot of time dealing with this error even though I had set `AutomaticChallenge = true`.

Turns out you will get the same error if you put `app.UseIdentity();` after `app.UseMvc(routes => ...)`. Now that I know the answer it's obvious. It's because all this middleware happens in the order you add it.

This causes the "*No authentication handler is configured*" error:

```
    public void Configure(...)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute(...) }; );

        app.UseIdentity();
    }
```

This does not cause the error:

```
    public void Configure(...)
    {
        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute(...); });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The same seems to apply to Uapp.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication() and app.UseCookieAuthentication()

Comment: After one year still valid for me. Thx

Comment: My error was this ordering of calls (since I was mocking authentication for integration testing). I would never have guessed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Put this on Configure method.

```
        app.UseIdentity();
```

Comment: I think you mean `Configure`, not `ConfigureServices`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was solved for me by making sure the cookies scheme was consistently named wherever it was referenced. e.g.:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // if using IdentityServer4
    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.AuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationScheme = Constants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        ...
    })

    services.AddIdentity<MyUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = Constants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        ...
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = Constants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme,
        AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
        AutomaticChallenge = true
    });
}
```

And when interacting with the authentication middleware. e.g.:

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(Constants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme, cp);
```

Comment: After implementing the first answer regarding "options.AutomaticAuthentication was split into options.AutomaticAuthenticate and options.AutomaticChallenge", I still received the same error, but after replacing the upper-case "Cookies" from the sample to lower case (as it was spelled in another place), my app started to work! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you use `app.UseIdentity();` and some other login middleware such as `UseFacebookAuthentication` make sure `app.UseFacebookAuthentication()` is AFTER `app.UseIdentity();`.

Comment: Solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

another possibility is missing the following setting in Configure

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication();
```

Comment: This is now obsolete

Answer (score 0):

While it's tempting to place much of our configuration settings within the `startup.cs` file, it seems that the preferred way of doing things is to set your  `app.UseCookieAuthentication()` - sans options - within the `startup.cs` file, and then place all of the 'options' and other details within a separate file.

Sort of like what we were doing with how the `Global.asax` file had pointers to the `App_Start` folder files in Asp.Net vBefore.

I suffered similar pain while trying to configure EF/Sql in the `startup.cs`, and by moving all 'options' outside of `startup.cs` things worked much better.

ALSO: take note of the Fredy Wenger comment to your question that points out the 'renaming' of many of the namespaces from v -8beta to v -RC1-final.