# No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.External

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, asp.net-core

I am building an api using asp.net 5 rc2.  I am trying to implement openiddict-core, found [here](https://github.com/openiddict/core) for local accounts and i also want to allow for users to use external logins, such as google.

I have set it all up, but when i try to implement google authentication, and i call this code

`var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();`

I get the error message in the title.

On the client i am using Satellizer found [here](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer), which takes care of opening the google prompt window and send the callback to my AuthController Google method, which is the normal ChallengeResult code you see in other mvc6 examples.

I have wrote code to get the users details manually and that works, but i thought i would use the already built signInManager instead, rather than reproducing the wheel...

I may have not set things up correctly, as all the examples seem to use cookies, which i am guessing is because they are mvc6 web applications, not an api.  I do not want to use cookies, but this could be my problem.

Now for some code.

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add MVC services to the services container.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(_configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddOpenIddict(); // Add the OpenIddict services after registering the Identity services.
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // use jwt bearer authentication
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
        options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.Audience = "http://localhost:5000/";
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
    });

    // Add all the external providers you need before registering OpenIddict:
    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
        //options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        options.ClientId = "XXX";
        options.ClientSecret = "XXX";
    });
    //app.UseFacebookAuthentication();

    app.UseOpenIddict();

    // Enable all static file middleware
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // Enable Mvc for view controller, and 
    // default all routes to the Home controller
    app.UseMvc(options =>
    {
        options.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
}
```

AuthController.cs

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

    public AuthController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
    }

    [HttpPost("google")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleAsync([FromBody] ExternalLoginModel model)
    {
        // THIS IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();


        return Ok();
    }
}
```

ExternalLoginModel.cs

```
public class ExternalLoginModel
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825058/no-authentication-handler-is-configured-to-handle-the-scheme-automatic)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried registering the Identity middleware by adding `app.UseIdentity();` before you register the GoogleAuthentication middleware?

Comment: You are right, if i add this it works fine.  But this uses cookies, how can i not use cookies??

Comment: It does appear to use cookies and I appreciate your initial comment stated that you don't want to use them. However, the method you're calling here `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` makes use of cookie authentication when it makes this call `var auth = new AuthenticateContext(Options.Cookies.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);`. You can find that code here: [SignInManager.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/58b2cf6c7dc946d0fce27f1fda150bbeb0e1a1fd/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/SignInManager.cs).

Comment: Have you taken a look at Pinpoint's other framework [ASOS](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server)? I'm using it currently and am having a good experience so far. I also believe it would be more suitable for your requirements. There is also a lot more documentation for it currently on StackOverflow, openiddict is still relatively young in comparison.

Comment: Does this sound like the sort of thing you're looking to do [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044879/is-it-possible-to-use-an-external-identity-provider-in-a-web-api-with-asp-net-5/33148160#33148160)