# No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Identity.Application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I receive the above error after I have successfully registered a user and confirmed authentication. The error occurs when I try to call

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(applicationUser, isPersistent);
```

I first assign the service to the IServiceCollection with this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>(
            config => { config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = async ctx =>
                    {
                        if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                        }
                        await Task.Yield();
                    }
                };
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<VisualJobsDbContext, int>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and in my Config method of startup I call `app.UseIdentity();` before the call to app.UseMvc

if I change my call to be:

```
var myVal = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(applicationUser, password, true, false);
```

them myVal is goes to 'Failed' I do not get any error thrown

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `app.UseIdentity();` into `Startup.cs` `Configure` method as in this answer [No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.External](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763335/no-authentication-handler-is-configured-to-authenticate-for-the-scheme-microsof)

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions

Comment: It appears that UseIdentity() is now deprecated.