# ASP.NET Core Identity No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'd like to use the Identity implementation with the EF Core but without the automatic redirects for Status 400 and 401.
So I've put in

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = null;
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = null;
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = null;
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
            });
```

The last option disables the redirects, but I'd also like to use the AuthorizeAttribute in my REST-Controllers.

I've a login service and use cookies.

The login service without the AuthorizeAttribute works as expected.
But my services in need of Authorization throws an exception:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<ChallengeAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at TimeGatherWebApi.Client.Api.APIV1.<ApiReportEntriesPostWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__20.MoveNext() in C:\Users\makolb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TimeGather\src\TimeGatherWebApi.Client\Api\APIV1.cs:line 407
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TimeGatherWebApi.Test.Controllers.Api.ApiRequestControllerTest.<CreateReportEntryTest>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Users\makolb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TimeGather\test\TimeGatherWeb.Test\Controllers\Api\ApiRequestControllerTest.cs:line 50
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Result Message: 
Test method TimeGatherWebApi.Test.Controllers.Api.ApiRequestControllerTest.CreateReportEntryTest threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic
```

If I set AutomaticChallenge to true the response is a 302-redirect by the framework instead of the required e.g. 401 status.

If I set AutomaticAuthenticate to false I don't get the Authentication cookie on login by the framework.

If I remove the AuthorizeAttribute the service works but I've to check the cookie in my own code.

Is there a way to get this to work?

I've found some posts with same exception but they are looking for different solutions.

Comment: Cookies are a bad fit for REST auth, you should be using Bearer tokens instead.

Comment: See answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763335/no-authentication-handler-is-configured-to-authenticate-for-the-scheme-microsof

Comment: I've already seen this. I've done it like it is requested there.